# Support of ECMAScript 2015 in gulp-angular-filesort

Tags: ecmascript-6, gulp

How can I know which language features **gulp-angular-filesort** supports?
I mean, I'm trying to add this line to a js file:

```
var [a1,a2]=[1,2];
```

and I get the following error:

```
[10:27:24] [AngularFilesort] Error in plugin 'gulp-angular-filesort'
```

Message:
    Error in parsing: "main\home\welcome\welcome.controller.js", Line 14: Unexpected token [

I have this line in package.json: **"gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",**
Is there a way to make this plug in work with new features of ecmascript?

Comment: You could probably fork its dependency, ng-dependencies to support ES6. Any way, it doesn't make much sense. If you're using a build step, you could transpile it to ES5 or use JS modules.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of stuff i don't have much knowledge of. We're using a prebuilt gulp flow from an admin angular material template we bought. I wish that gulp-angular-filesort would be updated to es2015. Thanks a lot estus for this important info.

Comment: It depends on how things are done there, but it seems to me that the easiest way to fix this is to transform js files with Babel to ES5 before they are piped to gulp-angular-filesort. And the smartest way is to refactor codebase to use modules instead of gulp-angular-filesort and concatenation - via Webpack, Browserify, RequireJS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue to make it work with ES6 code.

You'll need to pipe the stream with Babel, something like that:

```
.pipe(babel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))
.pipe(angularFilesort())
```

It worked for me.

Comment: In case you need to process the files further and don't want ES2015 code: you can use gulp-red with force:true after sorting the files to force to reload them from disk so the es2015 babelfications are "overwritten"...